# PostgresSQL: Loading files with non UTF-8 Filenames - pg_ls_dir() and pg_read_binary_file()

Tags: postgresql

I have thousands of documents to upload to a Postgres database as blob content however I constantly get an error when trying to use pg_read_binary_file() as the filenames contain characters not supported by the database/these functions.

```
select pg_read_binary_file(full_filepath) 
from documents
```

'[image: Error Message:]

Each file is in a separate folder so I took the full directory path with no filename and then concat with pg_ls_dir() but get the same error

```
select pg_read_binary_file(file_location)||pg_ls_dir(file_location)) 
from documents
```

Is there a way to read the file in the directory without specifying the filename itself? I have tried wildcard combinations but no luck. Both the above work for files with ascii filenames or if I manually rename a problematic file.

Comment: in which operating system are you performing this task?

Comment: What does `non UTF8 filenames` mean? And what's the actual file system? NTFS and exFAT for example are strictly UTF16. On Linux, many if not most file systems just store bytes which means different applications could store file names using different encodings

Comment: The error I see is *...could not open file* (FYI, **do not use images** for textual data). This could be due to any number of things. Read [Admin function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html) *9.27.9. Generic File Access Functions* for the restrictions on this function.

Comment: I am using DBeaver on windows to try and import the documents which are a mixture of every imaginable file type into a postgres database. 

I think it comes down to the pg functions only able to read UTF-8 or ASCII char but the filenames have got all sorts in.

Ideally I would import whatever document is in the folder without ever letting the DB worry about the filename.

Comment: Post some example of the problematic filenames. But in general, yes, if the name is being read it will need to be limited to readable characters.

Comment: Thanks. All the filenames have identifiable information in o I cant share I'm afraid. The characters can be anything from Chinese symbols to variations of hyphens. 

If possible I really want to somehow use:
pg_read_binary_file(full_filepath)
But completely ignore the name of the file in location as it's all stored in the DB metadata anyway.